# Unpaired vs Paired t-test

Tags: t-test

Should I be doing a paired or unpaired 2 sample t-test for my data?

I have 5 age groups (e.g. 0-44, 45-65, and so forth), and I have data for a 7-year period of deaths per those age groups. Should I be doing a paired 2 sample 2 test as the deaths are directly related to the ages?

Comment: Can you clarify what is your hypothesis and how, exactly, is your data structured?

Comment: > H~0~: That an increase in age does not increase total occurance of death on average over a 7 year period.
> H~1~: That an increase in age does increase total occurance of death on average over a 7 year period.,

data is structured in a 2 column table, headers being age | deaths, then  rows below with 0-44 under age, and then 1234 in deaths, next row 45-64, then 12345 in deaths etc

the age groups are 0-44, 45-64, 65-74, 75-84, 85+ @AdamO

Comment: And your data is just counts of deaths? That is to say, you don't know the denominator?

Comment: yes, the data was originally given as the total number of deaths per that age group, per month, per year, to which i totaled the number of deaths per month per year for that one age group, and averaged that. We have other data (like deaths by disease, deaths by gender) but the data used here is only for deaths total per age group

Alternatively, do you think that me comparing whether there is a sig. difference between cancer and dementia deaths over 7 years fits the criteria for 'comparing two things and you need to ensure your dependent variable is continuous.'?

Comment: Others may disagree, but in my epi training, a central theme was that an analysis of deaths alone is at best useless, and at worst misleading. We often hear that a leading cause of death may be X or Y, but why should we care - we will all die of *something* - that I may die 30 or 40 years *sooner* from a rare cause is a significant reduction in DALYs and QALYs. To coin a phrase from Erdos, I don't think these data are "ripe" for analysis. Merge a few additional sources and firm up the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on what you said, you shouldn't do it with a paired test unless you are sure that your samples are paired through the time the data is measured.